# Paypal Marketplace Seller

Tags: paypal

I'm struggling to pick the right Paypal solution for a small marketplace website.

The site has a number of vendors and customers buy directly from them. There is no commission or complication - payment is direct, buyer to vendor.

It crosses my mind that although I'm the merchant, I'm not the final funds recipient - so I can't see how I can make this work. I'd like to use Express, but I'm not sure that I can set the funds recipient to a third party account.

I don't want to use Adaptive. I've tried that before and it has some features missing (mostly relating to verified addresses, ability to list invoice items etc).

It also crosses my mind that if buyer A sends to Vendor B through the site, then there can be no IPN as the merchant is not the final recipient.

Really I'm looking for the right way to go to deploy a solid Paypal solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Express Checkout for this.  They vendors would just need to grant API permissions to your API username so that your user name has the permissions to execute Express Checkout API calls on their account.  This will allow you directly process the transactions on their PayPal account.  You can also pass over the IPN URL in the API call that you would like to have the IPN sent to.  Also by passing it over in the API call, it will override the one set in the account for the particular transaction you pass it over for.  This way the merchant/vendor can still use the one they may have set in their account for something else.

Comment: Thanks Chad - you know your stuff :-) Is there any other way to do it where the marketplace does not require the end recipient Paypal user to have to authorise an API? I want to wipe out that possibility first - even if it's a Paypal Pro or a Parallel payment with the merchant amount set to zero.

Comment: With Express Checkout they would have to give you some type of authorization.  If you were using Website Payments Standard, you could just populate the email address of the person's PayPal account that your wanting to receive the funds into the button code.  There would not need to be any special end user granting access to your API user name as it would not use API.  Otherwise, without granting permissions to your API username, you would have to use their API credentials.

Comment: Are there any security risks for the end recipient granting api permission like this? Can a rogue application send money / view balance etc? Or is it strictly limited to being able to authorise payment?

Comment: There are not security risk as long as the are assigning your API username the correct permissions.  There are other permissions for running refunds, downloading history and etc, but you would just need the permissions granted for performing Express Checkout options on their account.  So your API would only be able to put money into their account.  It would not be able to refund payments, unless the account grants permissions to your API to be able to issue refunds.