# Bypass Paypal Seller Credentials

Tags: paypal

Maybe this is an starter question, but I didn't found a really good answer.

I'm developing an application that (simplifying) will allow users to create items to sell. These items could be purchased and the buyer should pay over Paypal directly to seller, without financial intervention on our part. I mean, Paypal Button should initiate a payment with the seller as recipient.

It's possible to do this? (I am assuming that is not a good practice store all sellers client-id/client-secret)

Is there a 'best practice paper'?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519698/paypal-marketplace-seller), but I want to explore another ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storring a clientid/secret is a good practice if you want to fully manage those payments, but if you need a quick solution for some payments, there is the `payee` object: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, starting with Preston PHX answer and using Python Flask and [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/).

If needed, here is the working code: https://github.com/albertofojo/flaskpaypal